# Select either <numberA>\textwidth or <numberB>\textheight according to criteria

Tags: graphics

I have pictures with different aspect ratios. I want to keep the aspect ratio in each of my inserted pictures.

As an option to `\includegraphics` I would to have

```
height = 0.6\textheight
```

if the width of the image is greather than 0.7*`\textwidth` when the option `height = 0.6\textheight` is invoked, and

```
width = 0.7\textwidth
```

if the width of the image is less than or equal to 0.7*`\textwidth` when the option `height = 0.6\textheight` is invoked.

Is this possible to get *automatically*?

P.S. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: store image in box and than measure its width. if it is bigger than `0.7\textwidth` than use `includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{...}`, otherwice you use `\includegraphics[width=9.7\textwidth]{...}`  ... but i'm sure that you know this :-)

Comment: @Zarko Hmm! I'm, not sure exactly how to do thiis; can you please give a complete MWE in an answer?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense: if the width is more than `\textwidth`, you'd get an overfull.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You should look at the [`adjustbox` package](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox). It allows settings like `min height`, `max height`, `min width` and `max width`.

Comment: @Werner That looks interesting. Can you give an answer with the proper use? `:-)`

Comment: meanwhile (when i had dinner :-) you got two answers ... i liked the second one ...

Comment: Me too; egreg always gives impressive answers.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Can you provide some use-case examples? I can't figure out what the options should be based on your discussion.

Comment: Example: I have two images; one with the dimentions 976x845 and one with 801x892. If I set the option to the `\includegraphics` of the second image to `width = 0.7\textwidth`, the figure will take up too much vertical space on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the necessary test for not going off the textwidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\svendbox}

\newcommand{\svendincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \sbox{\svendbox}{\includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight,#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\svendbox>0.7\textwidth
    \ifdim\wd\svendbox>\textwidth
      \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\svendbox}}%
    \else
      \usebox{\svendbox}%
    \fi
  \else
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\svendbox}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\svendincludegraphics{example-image}

\noindent
\svendincludegraphics[angle=90]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

As you see you can also specify additional keys for `\includegraphics`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. It does what Zarko suggested in his comment.

```
\newbox\mybox
\def\myincludegraphics#1{
    \setbox\mybox\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}
    \ifdim\wd\mybox>0.7\textwidth\relax
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{#1}
    \else
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{#1}
    \fi
}
```

Comment: this would add a lot of space if used in horizontal mode, also appears to be missing a `}` in the `\setbox` and missing the `height` specification on the initial loading. (the request is to check the width after scaling the height)

Comment: I could delete this; the other answers seem to be much better.

Answer (score 1):

i'm late with my answer, but anyway let me elaborate my comment. it is more rude than other, but here we are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\imagesize
\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\widthtreshold
\setlength\widthtreshold{0.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\sbox\imagesize{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
\settowidth\imagewidth{\usebox{\imagesize}}

\ifdim\imagewidth<\widthtreshold
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\else
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\fi

\medskip
\sbox\imagesize{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textwidth]{example-image}}
\settowidth\imagewidth{\usebox{\imagesize}}

\ifdim\imagewidth<\widthtreshold
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\else
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

to image i didn't add size of images (that they stay small). if image width is shorter than `0.7\textwidth` is shown image A, otherwise image B.